# Topology checker won't highlight in red the overlaps

Tags: qgis-plugins, overlapping-features, topology

I´m using QGIS and trying to find overlaps in a shapefile.

When I use the Topology Checker I get 24 results for overlaps, but they are not highlighted in red as they used to the last times I did the same. I have the "show errors" box checked. Instead I can only see which polygons have overlaps (highlighted in pale greenish-blue). The polygons are big and I cant't find where the overlaps are.

What do I need to do in order to get the overlaps highlighted in red again?

In the photo I show an obvious overlap that I did on purpose to show the problem (no red highlight). The same polygon has an other overlap which I can't find

[image: In the photo I show an obvious overlap that I did on purpose to show the problem (no red highlight). The same polygon has an other overlap which I can't find]